# Conditional import with ES Module ( fetch / node-fetch )

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, fetch-api, node-fetch

I'm writting a JS code that can be use eather for `Node` application or for `JavaScript` web browser application.

Since Node 17.5 it's now possible to use the native `fetch API` from JavaScript.

I wonder if there is a way to use a kind of conditinal import for ES Module working like this :

```
if fetch exist => use fetch
else import fetch from node-fetch
```

I've tried something like this :

```
if(!fetch) {
    import fetch from 'node-fetch'
}

...
fetch(url).then(res => ...)
...
```

But it raises an error as `fetch is undefined`.
Note:  I made my test using `node@18`

Has someone an idea to solve my probleme ?

Answer :

I Found a solution thanks to @Positivity's answer :

```
let fetcher = fetch ?? await import('node-fetch');
```

Then I use `fetcher` as fetch.
If I rename the variable to `fetch` it throw an error :

```
Cannot access 'fetch' before initialization
```

Finnaly found a solution to this error :

```
if(!fetch) {
    const fetch = await import('node-fetch');
}
// else => fetch is already declared
```

Answer (score 2):

The import() call, commonly called dynamic import, is a function-like expression that allows loading an ECMAScript module asynchronously and dynamically into a potentially non-module environment.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/import

so this should do a conditional import on supported node versions:

```
let fetch = fetch ?? await import('node-fetch')
```

Comment: Almost solve my problme, I had this error : `Cannot access 'fetch' before initialization` so I renamed the variable to `fetcher` (for exemple). If you have another solution to avoid this error, please do.

Comment: @nem0z Glad it helped, I've edited to solve the code for the initialization error

Comment: Thx, unfortunately I still have this error. I'm currently doing my tests using `node@18` + `"type": "module"`

Comment: I think this is because of the place you're using the fetch... as this is an async call your code should make use of this after this is resolved, can you show the context you're actually calling fetch

Comment: I edited my question with the solution I just found. The error is raised by `let fetch = fetch ??`, so I don't think it's about the rest of the code. This code is just a `class` with a method `request` that return `fetch(url).then(res => ...)`